# Why doesn't VirtualBox shared files show up as network share?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, network-shares

I have a virtualbox instance running with Windows 7 as the guest and macOS as the host. I'm sharing my coding directory `bin` to the guest and have access to it:

[image]

As you can see the share is in the `network` folder, but if I run the `net share` command the output is just the usual output:

```
>net share

Share name   Resource                        Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C$           C:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote Admin
The command completed successfully.


>
```

Another thing is that I have to `pushd` into the share in order to access it. Why is it that this share shows up under the `network` folder but I cannot see it in my `net share` command?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. VirtualBox uses the system drive `Z:\` as the shared drive. So if you (for example) wanted to enumerate all system drives and figure out which on was for VBox you could do so like this, using python:

```
def do_logical_drive_enum():
    discovered_drives = []
    drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
    drives = drives.split("\000")[:-1]
    for drive in drives:
        try:
            discovered_drives.append(win32api.GetVolumeInformation(drive))
        except:
            pass
    print discovered_drives
```